# Flutter How to Get Rid of Default fillColor for the First Item of DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

Question: **title**

So I have this DropdownButton

[image]

And here is the DropdownMenuItem

[image]

As you can see, the first item has a grey color on the background. So how to remove it?

To be more clear, here is what I want to achieve

[image]

**Navbar Snippet:**

```
class Navbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavbarState createState() => _NavbarState();
}

class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> {
  action() {
    print('test');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          NavbarLogo(),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              NavbarItem(
                title: 'welcome',
                navigationPath: RouterDashboardView.welcomeView,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 50.0),
              NavbarItemDropdown(
                items: ['labelExitLabel', 'labelExitLabel', 'actionExitAction'],
                functions: [action],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing fancy, just contains a logo, a text and the dropdown

**NavbarDropdown Snippet:**

```
class NavbarItemDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final List<Function> functions;

  const NavbarItemDropdown({
    Key key,
    @required this.items,
    this.functions,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavbarItemDropdownState createState() => _NavbarItemDropdownState();
}

class _NavbarItemDropdownState extends State<NavbarItemDropdown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
        items: widget.items.map((String _value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: _value,
            child: _value.contains('label')
                ? Text(
                    '${_value.split('label')[1]}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                  )
                : Text('${_value.split('action')[1]}'),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String _value) {
          if (_value.contains('action')) widget.functions[0]();
        },
        hint: Text('TestDropDown'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the highlighted background indicates the currently selected value. Are setting value in the constructor by chance? If so, leaving value unset should ensure that no value is selected by default.

Comment: I don't use value because I don't want to change the hintText. Let me add my snippet

Comment: Using this snippet, I was only able to reproduce the issue the first time I ran it. Even after restarting my AVD it works as expected if I am clicking on the dropdown. My best guess is that the widget is getting focus to make a selection from the keyboard as the current keyboard selection will be highlighted (for example, pressing space bar or the arrow keys).

Comment: If so, how to make the DropdownMenuItem unselectable for the label. But it doesn't even receive keyboard input at all from the beginning.

Comment: It could potentially have something to do with the parent widget that this is being used in. Are you able to share the code where you are using this widget? Also, what version of Flutter are you using and on which OS(s) are you running the app on?

Comment: I have edited the question again. Actually the highlight could be moved with 'Tab' key. I am currently using Flutter 1.14.1-pre.20 and Windows 10

Comment: Unfortunately I am still unable to reproduce the issue using the same version of Flutter.